# MySQL, PHP: split up output table in categories

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, pdo

Hello guys,
I've a problem and I hope anybody can help me.

My MySQL database looks like this:

[image: database]

I would like to output these data in a table this way:

[image: output]

My actual code looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>

<?php
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
include "$root/config.php";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM TestTable ORDER BY name');
$stmt->execute();


$results = $stmt->fetchAll();


if (empty($results)) {
    echo 'Error!'; 
} else {
foreach( $results as $row ) {
        echo
        "
        <tr>
        <td class=\"left\">".$row['name']."</td>
        <td class=\"right\">".$row['address']."</td>
        </tr>
        ";
}
}

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Output looks like this actual:

[image: actual output]

What to do to have the name of the profession always on top, when the profession is not the same like in the row before?

To sove this issue I've this code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli(host,username,password,db_name);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TestTable ORDER BY profession, name";
$array = [];
$html = "";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if (!isset($array[$row['profession']])) {
                $array[$row['profession']] = array();
            }
            $array[$row['profession']][] = $row['name'];
        }
    }



foreach ($array as $profession => $name) {
    $html .= '<p style="font-weight:bold">'.$profession.'</p>';
    foreach ($name as $name) {
        $html .= '<p class="name">'.$name.'</p>';
    }
}
echo $html;

?>
```

[image: output with second code]

But I need the street in this table too. And I need this code with PDO not MySQLi. I tried to manage this, but without success.

Can anybody help me please?

Greetings,
David.

Comment: `ORDER BY profession`, then keep track of the last profession seen and output a new header if it differs.

Comment: What @eggyal said. Or change `$array[$row['profession']][] = $row['name'];` to `$array[$row['profession']][] = $row;`. You now have all data (not just the name) in your associative array, organized by profession. Simply output the keys you need in your table.

Comment: And do not mix pdo and mysqli. Decide which one you use and stick with it!

Comment: @Shadow, I know. Therefore I wrote "I need this code with PDO not MySQLi". I want to use PDO for my code. But I don't know how to "convert".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM TestTable ORDER BY profession, name');
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (empty($results)) {
   echo 'Error!'; 
} else {
$profession = $row['profession'];
foreach( $results as $row ) {
  if ($row['profession'] <>$profession) {
       echo "<tr><td>". $row['profession']."</td></tr>";
     }
    echo "<tr>
    <td class=\"left\">".$row['name']."</td>
    <td class=\"right\">".$row['address']."</td>
    </tr>
    ";
   $profession = $row['profession'];
}
}
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much. Thank you! Thank you. You are awesome.